# Would a NULL value in the DB return a null value in the dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, null

Does a `NULL` value for a (string) column in the database would return a `null` value in the dataset record in C#  (by default)? Or would it turn into an empty string in the dataset?

Comment: Why not try it and see ? I am guessing it will return null though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In .NET depending on what technologies you use, a `NULL` value will be returned as `null` or as [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

When using ADO.NET (`System.Data`), a database `NULL` value will generally be returned as DbNull.Value, whereas in (for example) Entity Framework, it will be returned as `null`.

If you are not doing any other processing, the value will not be returned as an empty string and in no case as the string value "null".

Answer (score 3):

Normally it will return the value [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or throw a `InvalidCastException`. Depending on what you are going to it could turn the `DBNull.Value` in to a `null`, but usually when stuff like that happens it really is doing the `DBNull.Value` check for you and just hiding it. It would not be hard to make a extension method of your own that did it too.

```
public static string GetStringWithNullCheck(this IDataReader reader, int index)
{
    if(reader.IsDBNull(index))
        return null;
    return reader.GetString(index); //If we called this on a record that is null we get a InvalidCastException.
}
```

This distinction between `null` and `DBNull.Value` is most useful when calling [`ExecuteScalar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this allows you to tell the diffrence between "no records returned" and "record returned but the DB contained `NULL` as the value"

```
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if(result == null)
    {
        //0 rows where returned from the query
    }
    else if(result == DBNull.Value)
    {
        //Rows where returned but the value in the first column in the first row was NULL
    }
    else
    {
        //Result is the value of whatever object was in the first column in the first row
    }
}
```